# Is it necessary to call a destructor for "string" members within the object destructor?

Tags: c++, string, destructor

I created a class:

```
class Message {
public:
  Message(string sender, string message_text);
  Message(string sender);
  Message();

  ~Message();

  bool wasRead() const;
  void updateWasReadStatus();
  void printMessage() const;
private:
  string Sender_;
  string Text_;
  bool wasRead_;
};
```

When I implement the destructor, do I have to call explicitly the destructor for **Sender_** & **Text_**? Or are they called implicitly by the default destructor when I write (without implementing `~Message()` explicitly):

```
delete pMessage; //pointer to Message object
```

Anyhow, I implemented the destructor like this:

```
Message::~Message(){
    delete Sender_;
    delete Text_;
}
```

Is it OK? Should I count maybe on the default destructor in this case?

I understand (please correct me if I'm wrong):
when a default-destructor is called, it calls a destructor for each member:

- to an implemented one if it exists,
- to a default one if it doesn't exist.

If I don't get it right I would be grateful if someone can explain it to me.

Comment: If you didnt use `new`, you don't need to call `delete`.

Comment: All non-pointer class member's destuctors are called automatically after the class destructor completes. Any pointer members need to be `delete`ed if the class object *owns* the memory (particularly if you used `new` in the class).

Comment: what other commenters said: instead of `Message(string sender, string message_text);` you should do `Message(const string& sender, const string& message_text);`  this was a idiom in C++03. It can be bypassed in c++11, though **I** still think it's a good practice to offer inputs this way for a function. It avoids copying the string, that's all about it.

Answer (score 9):

No, you don't need. (And you must not !)

You are only responsible for the memory you have allocated with `new`, only then should you use `delete`.

Comment: In this case I should not implement a destructor? or should I implement an empty one?

Comment: @Day_Dreamer If you don't need to put any code in the destructor body, you usually don't need to provide the destructor at all. There are some exceptions, such as virtual destructors. Ps pass strings to functions as const reference.

Comment: thanks @NeilKirk. Maybe you can have a look in the edited version of the question, please. did I understand it right?